# Процесс преобразования C# кода в машинный код

Tags: c#, компиляция

Доброго времени суток. Сейчас изучаю технический аспект прохождения высокоуровневого языка к командам процессора на его выполнения на примере C#. Возникли некоторые не ясности, в связи с чем и обращаюсь за помощью. Составил маленькую диаграмму по прохождению кода с IDE к процессору и возникли вопросы:

1. На каком этапе и какой из компиляторов определяет для разрядности какого процессора нужно преобразование?
2. Как преобразуются метаданные из манифеста в компиляции к машинному языку?
3. Правильно ли понял данную тему? Если нет, то прошу поправить.
   Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Прикрепляю маленький скриншот, как я представляю себе этот процесс.
[image: Макет]

Comment: А JIT не опционален ли?

Comment: у тебя пропущена сама платформа `.Net`

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Как я понял из CLR via C#, процесс и значение /platform задается перед этапом компиляции (на скриншоте из книги в IDE), после чего происходит проверка на совместительность. Но мой вопрос в том, на каком этапе это происходит?

Comment: Кароче.   C# не машинный код, его процессор не прочтет.  твой написанный код преобразуется в байт код виртуальной машины.  эта машина читает этот байт код и начинает исполнять сама.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров вы что то путаете :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> На каком этапе и какой из компиляторов определяет для разрядности какого процессора нужно преобразование?

Компилятор C# → IL не обращает внимания на разрядность вообще. Он компилирует для формальной стековой машины, а не для физического процессора.

JIT-компилятор запускается **в рантайме**, при запуске приложения на целевой машине. Соответственно он совершенно точно знает целевой процессор и целевую платформу, и генерирует код для неё. Этот код существует лишь в памяти (а это значит, что при повторном запуске программы JIT-компиляция будет произведена повторно).

Кроме того, возможны различные варианты AOT-компиляции (например, [`ngen`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator) или [.NET Native](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/)) вместо JIT, при которой нативный для процессора образ создаётся из IL-кода заранее, до запуска приложения. При этом либо нужно заранее указывать целевую платформу (для .NET Native), либо компиляция сама проходит на целевой платформе (`ngen`).

Answer (score 5):

1. Только на этапе компиляции IL в машинный код генерируются специфические для разрядности команды. Если компилировать .NET сборку для `x86/x64/Any Cpu`, то IL код различаться не будет, будет различие только в 1 байте в метаданных сборки. В самом IL нет специфических команд, все они общие для всех разрядностей.
2. Метаданные просто превращаются в некоторые структуры в памяти процесса. Когда .NET код использует рефлексию, то происходит поиск по этим таблицам в памяти. Такой поиск неоптимизирован, использует сравнение строк, поэтому, как известно, рефлексия выполняется медленнее обычного кода.

Comment: А как IL компилятор распознает поддержку процессора, допустим для ARM?

Comment: @Rifter не понимаю, IL компилятор ничего не распознает, он генерирует общий код.